# Why does Safari freeze on YouTube HTML5 videos?

Tags: macos, safari, performance, youtube

I'm in [YouTube HTML5 trial](http://www.youtube.com/html5), and the experience is terrible with Safari.
Every video is lagging severely, and the browser gets unresponsive constantly.

I have zero problems with the Flash version, and Chrome handles HTML5 YouTube just fine.

Activity Monitor says **QTKitServer - Safari Web Content** grabs more than 100% CPU.
Can I fix this?

[image: image showing 100% cpu usage]

I have 17-inch Mid 2010 MacBook Pro running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2 with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: You should report your experiences via the "feedback" link on that YouTube HTML5 web page.

Comment: A bit more info on your computer could be useful too. OS version, model, year, etc.

Comment: @bneely: thanks. I just [reported it](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=566399903f25d1bf&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Safari. I went into /Library/Internet Plug-Ins and removed the two piece of Flash cruft (regretfully I'm at work, so I don't the exact file names.)  After a reboot, Safari worked much better, as did Chrome.  Not sure why Chrome improved, but it improved most of all.

Incidentally, I thought I was on a Flash free system previously, so I'm not sure how those bits got there.  If I need Flash, I just go to Develop -> Open Page With -> Chrome (you need to enable the Developer Menu, under Advanced in Preferences.)

Hope this help